# Is there an invisible bottom padding in flet alertDialog?

Tags: python, flet, flutter-alertdialog

Have made an alertDialog but it appears to have a huge padding in the bottom, but it isn´t asign by me, here is the code and a image of the dialog.

```
add_input_popup = ft.AlertDialog(
    title=ft.Text(" Introduce los datos de la entrada: ",max_lines=1,size = 18, color=ft.colors.BLACK, font_family = "Poppins", weight = ft.FontWeight.W_700),
    content=ft.Column([
            inputField,
            ft.Row([    
                popUpAddInput
            ]),
            ft.Container(    
            content = ft.ElevatedButton(content=(ft.Text("Añadir",size = 18, color=ft.colors.BLACK, font_family = "Poppins", weight = ft.FontWeight.BOLD)), on_click=add_input_close, bgcolor="WHITE",style=ft.ButtonStyle(overlay_color="#98E9CB,0.75")),
                alignment= ft.alignment.center,
                margin = ft.margin.only(top=10),
            ),
        ]),
    adaptive= True,
    on_dismiss=lambda e: (add_input_close),
    bgcolor= "#F8F8FA"

)
```

[APP IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGBVU.png) Look, I want to delete that bottom blank space.

Comment: Better use geometry layout.